# How to sum a specific option in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
[
   { id: "1", option { points: "1"} },
   { id: "2", option { points: "20"} },
   { id: "3", option { points: "4"} },
]
```

I'm trying to sum all the object`option` that have as property `points`, so I did:

```
 var total_points = this.my_arr.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b.option.points;
    }, 0);
```

but this return a concatenation of the index of each id, something like: 012, that is of course wrong.

The expected output is: 25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must convert your strings to numbers, for example:

```
var total_points = this.my_arr.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + parseInt(b.option.points);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, completely overlooked at it. Just a question, the value of the array are returned from the database, the ajax request will encode the result in json.. Is there a way that allow me to convert automatically the string in integer or I need to make each time a conversion?

Comment: @sfarzoso `JSON.parse()` will help you to convert json back

Comment: @CodeManiac I already use it, but it will return something like:  `{id: "5"}` instead of `{id: 5}`

Comment: @sfarzoso try this is in console and see `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({id:5}))`

Answer (score 1):

Correct your object and cast the `b` as `Number`. In the object the values are strings so when `+` is used with string `concatenations` happens not addition. That's why the `strings` are converted to `numbers` and then added

```js
var e=[
   { id: "1", option :{ points: "1"} },
   { id: "2", option :{ points: "20"} },
   { id: "3", option :{ points: "4"} },
]


 var total_points = e.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + Number(b.option.points);
    }, 0);
    console.log(total_points);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your object options is `string` when you use `+` operator b/w two `strings` it joins both of then. Use you convert string to number using `parseInt()` or `Number()`

```
var total_points = this.my_arr.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + parseInt(b.option.points);
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the string to a number, you can use `parseInt` for that, or even simpler prepend a `+` before the string.

This version works with **NaN**, **undefined** or **missing properties**:

```js
const data = [
   { id: "1", option: { points: "1" } },
   { id: "2", option: { points: "20" } },
   { id: "3", option: { points: "4" } },
   { id: "4", option: { points: NaN } },
   { id: "5", option: { points: undefined } },
   { id: "6", option: { } },
   { id: "7" },
];

const totalPoints = data.reduce((accum, elem) => {
  const value = elem.option && elem.option.points ? +elem.option.points : 0;
  return accum + value;
}, 0);

console.log(totalPoints);
```